# Query genre and sub genre of authors and books

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

I want to create a DB for books. The DB should include the tables shown bellow. 
suppose i wanted to write a query that returned `authors.first_name`, `author.last_name`, `works.title` of authors that wrote haiku poetry; where poetry is the genre and haiku is the sub genre.

I really have no idea how to write this query, is it even possible with the way I have the tables set up? I can return a list of all authors who write poetry with:

```
# to get authors who write poetry
 SELECT Authors.first_name, Authors.last_name
 FROM Authors 
 LEFT JOIN `author.genre` ON (Authors.authors_id  = `author.genre`.author_id)
 LEFT JOIN genre ON (`author.genre`.genre_id = genre.g_id)
 WHERE genre.genre = 'poetry'
```

db creation:

```
CREATE
TABLE Authors
(
authors_id INTEGER NOT NULL ,
first_name VARCHAR2 (16 CHAR) ,
last_name  VARCHAR2 (16 CHAR) ,
DOB        DATE ,
DOD        DATE
) ;
ALTER TABLE Authors ADD CONSTRAINT Authors_PK PRIMARY KEY ( authors_id ) ;

CREATE
TABLE "author.genre"
(
Authors_authors_id INTEGER NOT NULL ,
genre_g_id         INTEGER NOT NULL
) ;

CREATE
TABLE "authors.works"
(
works_ISBN         INTEGER NOT NULL ,
Authors_authors_id INTEGER NOT NULL
) ;

CREATE
TABLE genre
(
g_id  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
genre VARCHAR2 (32 CHAR) ,
descroptoin CLOB
) ;
ALTER TABLE genre ADD CONSTRAINT genre_PK PRIMARY KEY ( g_id ) ;

CREATE
TABLE sub_type
(
st_id      INTEGER NOT NULL ,
sub_type   VARCHAR2 (32 CHAR) NOT NULL ,
genre_g_id INTEGER NOT NULL
) ;
ALTER TABLE sub_type ADD CONSTRAINT sub_type_PK PRIMARY KEY ( st_id ) ;

CREATE
TABLE works
(
ISBN  INTEGER NOT NULL ,
Title VARCHAR2 (64 CHAR) NOT NULL ,
Description CLOB ,
num_pages INTEGER
) ;
ALTER TABLE works ADD CONSTRAINT works_PK PRIMARY KEY ( ISBN ) ;

CREATE
TABLE "works.genre"
(
works_ISBN INTEGER NOT NULL ,
genre_g_id INTEGER NOT NULL
) ;

ALTER TABLE "author.genre" ADD CONSTRAINT "author.genre_Authors_FK" FOREIGN KEY
( Authors_authors_id ) REFERENCES Authors ( authors_id ) ;

ALTER TABLE "author.genre" ADD CONSTRAINT "author.genre_genre_FK" FOREIGN KEY (
genre_g_id ) REFERENCES genre ( g_id ) ;

ALTER TABLE "authors.works" ADD CONSTRAINT "authors.works_Authors_FK" FOREIGN
KEY ( Authors_authors_id ) REFERENCES Authors ( authors_id ) ;

ALTER TABLE "authors.works" ADD CONSTRAINT "authors.works_works_FK" FOREIGN KEY
( works_ISBN ) REFERENCES works ( ISBN ) ;

ALTER TABLE sub_type ADD CONSTRAINT sub_type_genre_FK FOREIGN KEY ( genre_g_id
) REFERENCES genre ( g_id ) ;

ALTER TABLE "works.genre" ADD CONSTRAINT "works.genre_genre_FK" FOREIGN KEY (
genre_g_id ) REFERENCES genre ( g_id ) ;

ALTER TABLE "works.genre" ADD CONSTRAINT "works.genre_works_FK" FOREIGN KEY (
works_ISBN ) REFERENCES works ( ISBN ) ;
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use "." in your table names.

Comment: This looks like Oracle syntax but the question is tagged as mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this gets you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, w.title
FROM Authors a
INNER JOIN "authors.works" aw
On a.authors_id = aw.Authors_authors_id
INNER JOIN works w
On aw.works_ISBN = w.ISBN
INNER JOIN "works.genre" wg
On w.ISBN = wg.works_ISBN
INNER JOIN genre g
On wg.genre_g_id = g.g_id
INNER JOIN sub_type s
On g.g_id = s.genre_g_id
Where g.genre = 'poetry'
And s.sub_type = 'haiku';
```

It looks like you have genre for both the author and for the book. I used the book genre above since the query you asked for shows the title in the results and that seemed more relevant.